# PhoneGap Android Native navigation bar

Tags: android, cordova, cross-platform

I'm developing a Cross Platform app which is initially going to target Android devices, and iOS later. I am using PhoneGap. By now I've designed main screen for the app in Index.html, and have stuck upon adding Android's NATIVE navigation bar. Like one in this screen of -> [FourSquare app](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/phonegap/creating-apps-with-phonegap-lessons/fig01b.png)

After bit personal R&D, I have come to know about JQuery and WebView which are useful for embedding native UI, isn't it? But I couldn't have yet figure out, what exactly should I use to achieve this, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap uses HTML and CSS to create UI elements. You can use jQuery Mobile to make your life very easy in terms of UI. If you want that a header bar similar to the one in your link for example, you can see the header bar in jQuery Mobile on this page: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/headers/.

You can also make that header using custom HTML and CSS and there are many ways of doing this, however, I highly recommend jQuery Mobile if you are developing through PhoneGap.

Comment: From my understanding the WebView is what is shown when PhoneGap runs. Basically when you run a PhoneGap application, all UI is opened through a WebView or a webpage (except no browser is opened).

Comment: For example, this code <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a>
    <h1>My App</h1>
    <a href="#" data-icon="bars">Menu</a> will create a header on your WebView page.
</div>

Comment: I found this http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html link very helpful when I was starting up with PhoneGap. Lemme know if you need anymore help or clarification.

Comment: Please, do not use jQueryMobile in Phonegap! Check out: http://apachecordova.blogspot.de/2012/11/who-is-murdering-phonegap-its-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

In-case of menu, I've found and followed [THIS](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2012/11/building-native-menu-with-phonegap.html)

So, I hope method for navigation bar may not be much different. Rectify me, if so.